# How can I get different styled links on the same page and still have them use colorbox?

Tags: html, css, styles, colorbox, conflict

I'm building a webpage with several styled links like so:

```
<a class="green" href="green.htm">Link is green and becomes blue on mouse over</a>

<a class="red" href="red.htm">Link is red and becomes yellow on mouse over</a>
```

Then I have my css classes like so:

```
a.green {   color: green; }
a.green:hover { color: blue; }


a.red {       color: red; }
a.red:hover { color: yellow; }
```

But then I want **green.htm** and **red.htm** to be opened in a Colorbox... Obviously I can't use classes anymore as I need them for link coloring.

How can I get different styled links on the same page and still have them use colorbox?

UPDATE: 
I've resorted to use an onclick event to fireup the colorbox effect.

```
<a class="green" onclick="$.colorbox({innerWidth:500, innerHeight:300, href:'green.htm'});">Link is green and becomes blue on mouse over</a>
```

It ain't exactly pretty but it will do until some day I get a cleaner way of doing things I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<element class="red">
    all content of red.htm
</element>
<element class="green">
    all content of green.htm
</element>
```

Comment: I'm affraid that I don't understand what you meant. Did you mean to use something like a span to enclose the link? Something like: <span class="red"><a class="myColorbox">Link is red and becomes yellow on mouse over</a></span> ? I tried that but it doesn't work.. Tried the other way around with <span class="myColorbox"> and that didn't help either.